# Laravel - Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias:

Tags: php, laravel

I got this error message when trying to join multiple tables

```
Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (42000)
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'users' (SQL: select * from `prescriptions` inner join `doctors` on `prescriptions`.`doctor_id` = `doctors`.`id` inner join `users` on `doctors`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` inner join `patients` on `prescriptions`.`patient_id` = `patients`.`id` inner join `users` on `patients`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` inner join `pharmacies` on `prescriptions`.`patient_id` = `pharmacies`.`id` inner join `users` on `pharmacies`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` where `prescriptions`.`pharmacy_id` = 1)
```

My code is like this

```
$prescriptions = DB::table('prescriptions') 
        ->join('doctors', 'prescriptions.doctor_id', '=', 'doctors.id')
        ->join('users', 'doctors.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->join('patients', 'prescriptions.patient_id', '=', 'patients.id')
        ->join('users', 'patients.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->join('pharmacies', 'prescriptions.patient_id', '=', 'pharmacies.id')
        ->join('users', 'pharmacies.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->where('prescriptions.pharmacy_id',$pharmacy->id)
        ->get();
```

My ERD diagram

[image]

Comment: you are using 3 time 'user' table in join. so their alias should be unique. you can use users as a for first join. user as b for second join and user as c for third join. in short use unique alias for every join.

Comment: You are joining the table `users` thrice: `->join('users', 'doctors.user_id', '=', 'users.id')` and `->join('users', 'patients.user_id', '=', 'users.id')` therefore it isn't a unique alias.

Comment: did you try to specify what you want to select?

Comment: Pharmacies should be tied to patients, not to users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have correctly pointed out, the problem is that you've joined in the `users` table three times but since they have not been aliased, your database is unable to distinguish which table you mean when you try to use it in any way. The solution would be to alias each `users` table when you join them. For example:

```
$prescriptions = DB::table('prescriptions') 
    ->join('doctors', 'prescriptions.doctor_id', '=', 'doctors.id')
    ->join('users as du', 'doctors.user_id', '=', 'du.id')
    ->join('patients', 'prescriptions.patient_id', '=', 'patients.id')
    ->join('users as pu', 'patients.user_id', '=', 'pu.id')
    ...
    ->get([
        'du.name as doctor_name',
        'pu.name as patient_name',
        'prescriptions.description as description'
    ]);
```

To grab the doctor's name for example:

```
foreach ($prescriptions as $prescription) {
    echo $prescription->doctor_name;
}
```

However, I would suggest doing this with Eloquent instead:

```
$prescriptions = Prescription::where('pharmacy_id', $pharmacyId)
    ->with('patient', 'patient.user', 'doctor', 'doctor.user');
```

This will effectively run one query to select all prescriptions by the given `pharmacy_id` and then it will run subsequent queries to eagerly load in the associated patients (and their associated users) and those doctors (and their associated users).

If you don't need to load the pharmacy name or any other information about the pharmacy or its associated user, then you needn't bother load them in. If you do, it's as simple as following the above format and adding them to the `->with()` which will result in them being eager loaded.

After doing the above, you can access a patient's name like this:

```
foreach ($prescriptions as $prescription) {
    echo $prescription->patient->user->name;
}
```

This of course assumes you have your relations all correctly set up.

Comment: i try first. but how to select doctor's name, patient's name and description?

Comment: i already tried. no output appeared. just empty and no error message.

Comment: See my updated answer (the first block of code). I would strongly suggest the Eloquent route if you can do it that way.

Answer (score -1):

this is because you're using the same alias for 3 joins ..
this will do:

```
$prescriptions = DB::table('prescriptions') 
    ->leftJoin('doctors', function($join){
        $join->join('users as a', 'doctors.user_id', '=', 'a.id');
    })
    ->leftJoin('patients', function($join){
        $join->join('users as b', 'patients.user_id', '=', 'b.id');
    })
    ->join('pharmacies', function($join){
        $join->join('users as c', 'pharmacies.user_id', '=', 'c.id');
    })
    ->where('prescriptions.pharmacy_id',$pharmacy->id)
    ->get();
```

Comment: but how to select doctor's name, patient's name and description?